# Using JSON for jQuery validator rules and messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin at http://jqueryvalidation.org.

A typical jconfiguration might look like the following:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name",
        email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
});
```

Instead of including the rules and messages in my JavaScript file, I wish to include them in a separate JSON file.  Note that this question does not apply to using remote methods.

Is there a specific way to do this, or must I do the following:

```
$.getJSON("getValidation.json", function(json) {
    $(".selector").validate(json);
});
```

I recognize that this approach will not work should the rules require a callback as it will break the JSON.

Comment: What you've written looks like it should work.

Comment: I don't think there's any predefined way to do what you're doing, you need to get the JSON explicitly as you are.

Comment: @Barmar.  Haven't tested it, but I am confident that it will work.  Just didn't know if there was some builtin way of doing so.  I will, unfortunately, have rare cases of needing a call back in the rules.  When doing so, I will client side strip the tags (haven't thought too much how this will work), and a built in method would have been nice.

Comment: Since the question _"does not apply to using `remote` method"_, then maybe you should not have linked directly to the `remote` method.

Comment: @Sparky  Good point!  I went there to find out how they referred to it, and inadvertently used this link.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, json properties should be in quotes "rules": {
        "name": "required",
        "email": {
            "required": true,
            "email": true
        }
  But other than that, it should work

Comment: Agree, they are.  The example I showed you came from the jQuery Validator documentation.

Comment: The OP's code is 100% correct as it was used within the `.validate()` method.